# How to change Profile's default App

Tags: profile, app

I want to change All profile's default app to another app. 
I don't want to go on each profile then edit and then change default app.
I want to change it for all profile at once.

Comment: You could use the Force.com migration tool and download the XML for the profile, mass change the XML and then re-deploy the XML into your environment.

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe What exactly changes I need to make in XML to achieve the target.

Comment: Well if you change one profile , so switch the app for that profile only in Salesforce UI, download the profile and then match it with the others and then you will know what to change in the XML

Answer (score 3):

Under Setup visit `Build > Create > Apps`

Select `Edit` on the app you want to be the default, you can then select all the profiles you want to set the app as default for in the list at the bottom of the edit page:

[image]

Comment: I done same the way you suggested but I found that some of the profiles are disabled. Any clue on this.

Comment: If the app isn't visible for a profile you need to check the visible box, then save before you can check the default box.